# How can i access multiple row data in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, rows, multiple-value

I want to get multiple row data from table in controller .
like i have a likes table 
columns are id and value
i want to get like this statement . select * from likes where id is this and value is that .

Comment: can u explain exactly what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand your question, but in order to " select * from likes where id is this and value is that ", try

```
App\Likes::where('id', this)
          ->where('value', that)
          ->get();
```

hope that helps. read more https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses